# How to freeze a radio button list at selected radio button in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, radio-button, freeze

How to freeze a radio button list at selected radio button in ASP.net? My code has a radio button list like:

- MyPlayer
- MyABC
- MyNum
- MyD
- MyK
- MyM
- MyC
- MyU
- MyY
- MyPop
- MyCost
- MyLast
- MyCo
- MyName
- MyID
- MyCust
- MyStudent
- MyOffice
- MyVehicle
- MyVoucher

These are all in a scrollbar Radio Button List which is fixed upto some height that only top few is visible after page load or refresh. I want to freeze it wherever the selected radio button is, so that user don't have to scroll down to see what he has selected in case he selects the last options of the list.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
ListItem selectedItem = radioButtonList.SelectedItem;
selectedItem.Attributes.Add("onload", "this.focus();");
```